# What happens if I receive the push notification when the app is launched

Tags: android, ios, ux-field, ux-designer, app

I would like to know what happens if I receive the push notification when the app is launched.

Is it a default behavior in ios or Android like the notification will slide in from the top when the app is launched?

or

Will the push notification not show if the app is launched?

---

I am working the UI flow. Originally, I use toast to remainder the users when the app is launched, and I use push notification to remainder the users when the app is not launched. However, if I have no idea if I use push notification , does any notification show when the app is notification? I push notification will notice user when the app is launched, then I will not use toast.

Really appreciate!!

Comment: Are you looking for technical answers? Could you elaborate more regarding how it relates as a UX question.

Comment: I am working the UI flow. Originally, I use toast to remainder the users when the app is launched, and I use push notification to remainder the users when the app is not launched. However, if I have no idea if I use push notification , does any notification show when the app is notification? I push notification will notice user when the app is launched, then I will not use toast.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, it shows (as a slide from top notification center) if app is not in front of user (i.e he is not using it), else Apple signals the app to handle the notification (silently) and doesn't disturb the user.

In Android, AFAIK it would should show up in notification center irrespective of app's running state. However developers can handle it and stop the notification from being shown too

Could you add more context. If the question is will a push notification show when app is running, then in iOS it doesn't as app is in front of users

Comment: Yes, my question is "will a push notification show when app is running". If I want push notification show when app is running, how to appear in the app? Slide in from the top ?

Comment: Really appreciate your answer

Comment: Regret the delay, and it won't show if app is running, however if its in background or not running, then yes, it would slide in from top